# music21 parse files parallel

Tags: python, music21

I would like to parse midi files parallel using music21 library, because sometimes script hang-ups and CPU is loaded to 100%. The problem is that my function return list of notes from files and when I use `common.runParallel` for this function I get `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

```
from music21 import converter, instrument, note, chord, common

for file in glob.glob("midi/preludes/*.mid"):
    files.append("midi/preludes"+file)


def get_notes():
    notes = []

    midi = converter.parse(file)

    print("Parsing %s" % file)

    notes_to_parse = None

    try:   
        s2 = instrument.partitionByInstrument(midi)
        notes_to_parse = s2.parts[0].recurse()
    except:  
        notes_to_parse = midi.flat.notes

    for element in notes_to_parse:
        if isinstance(element, note.Note):
            notes.append(str(element.pitch))
        elif isinstance(element, chord.Chord):
            print('.'.join(str(n) for n in element.normalOrder))
            notes.append('.'.join(str(n) for n in element.normalOrder))

    with open('data/notes', 'wb') as filepath:
        pickle.dump(notes, filepath)

    return notes

output = common.runParallel(files, parallelFunction=get_notes())
```

How can I fix this?

EDID

I change function to this:

```
def get_notes_parallel(file):
    notes = []

    midi = converter.parse(file)

    print("Parsing %s" % file)

    notes_to_parse = None

    try:   
        s2 = instrument.partitionByInstrument(midi)
        notes_to_parse = s2.parts[0].recurse()
    except:  
        notes_to_parse = midi.flat.notes

    for element in notes_to_parse:
        if isinstance(element, note.Note):
            notes.append(str(element.pitch))
        elif isinstance(element, chord.Chord):
            print('.'.join(str(n) for n in element.normalOrder))
            notes.append('.'.join(str(n) for n in element.normalOrder))

    with open('data/notes', 'wb') as filepath:
        pickle.dump(notes, filepath)

    return notes

notes = common.runParallel(files, parallelFunction=get_notes_parallel)
notes = [item for list in notes for item in list]
```

and it's working good

Comment: if you return "notes" you'll lose much of the parallel speedup.

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert I'm waiting for your response :) how can I correct this?

Comment: That all depends on what you plan to do next.  Can you do whatever you want to do inside the get_notes routine itself?  Can you return a list of strings representing what aspects of the notes you plan to work with?  In general, when running functions in parallel, pass in and out the lightest possible objects you can.  That usually means strings and integers and other small objects.  Otherwise the main routine spends most of its time deserializing objects.

Comment: For instance, if you want to do an analysis on the keys used across a repertoire of pieces, pass in the filename of the piece to analyze and return either a single Key object or even better just a string representing the key.  But don't parse the file outside the routine and don't return the Score or a list of notes.  Think of the barrier between the processes as like crossing an international border w/ high tariffs.  How can you travel as lightly as possible?

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert so I would like to get all notes from my midi files as string array. One big array with all notes from midi files.

Comment: The problem is that the `converter` stops on a random file every time you start it. As if he could not convert it.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
output = common.runParallel(files, parallelFunction=get_notes())
```

Because you put the `()` after the function name, you're not passing in the function itself, you're passing the result of having called the function. Just change it to:

```
output = common.runParallel(files, parallelFunction=get_notes)
```

That way you pass the actual function as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, it's correct and my function don't have incoming argument I fix it in my question and now it's working good

Comment: Why processor goes up to 100%? I do this parallel but sometimes its take very long time for 4 files.

Comment: Running things in parallel will definitely not decrease your CPU usage.

Comment: Yes but it still hangs up and after 5 min return `memory error`